# How to parse an html element with id having colon in php

Tags: php, parsing

I have html string in which some elements are having ids which contains colons like id=detailMainForm:PCTBiblio. So my question is how to parse such elements?

Comment: Are there no quotes around the id, like so: `id="detailMainForm:PCTBiblio"`? If not, you could just parse everything between `id=` and the next whitespace you encounter?

Comment: @domdom id is same as id="detailMainForm:PCTBiblio", Sorry  for mistyping

Comment: So what problem does the colon pose? Just parse everything within the quotes, including the colon.

Comment: Subhash, what came of this? Did this, in fact, turn out to be a bug in the parser project you l inked? Did you file a bug report or come up with a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer this based on what little information you supplied.

First, let me point out that the colon should be of no relevance to PHP. The parsing should be no different for `id`s with or without a colon. Also note that a colon is a valid character for the `id` attribute, both in HTML4 as well as HTML5 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)).

Now, to actually parse the `id`s, you can basically either make use of [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or use php's [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php). In the latter case, you could [search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) the source for `id="` and then [read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) everything from there until the next `"`.

Depending on what you're doing exactly, the [`DOMDocument` class](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) could also be useful to you.

Comment: I was following  https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser  to parse the html string I had. But I could not get the elements those were having ids with colon. So first i found and replaced ids with colons with ids without colons and then found the elements. Thank you for you answers.

Comment: @Subhash maybe you should file a bug report to the project then, as - from what I understand - a HTML parser should not fail because of colons within an id.